# What is the behavior of the "cousins" options in git rebase --rebase-merges?

Tags: git

For Git v2.22, the following information regarding the `--rebase-merges` option can be found on the [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---rebase-mergesrebase-cousinsno-rebase-cousins) documentation page:

> By default, or when no-rebase-cousins was specified, commits which do not have `<upstream>` as direct ancestor will keep their original branch point, i.e. commits that would be excluded by git-log's --ancestry-path option will keep their original ancestry by default. If the rebase-cousins mode is turned on, such commits are instead rebased onto `<upstream>` (or `<onto>`, if specified).

Unfortunately, the detailed documentation sections at the bottom of that page do not show any examples of the `no-rebase-cousins` or `rebase-cousins` options to `--rebase-merges`. I'm also not too familiar with `git log --ancestry-path` (I never use it), so that example doesn't help my understanding at all.

Can someone explain, with examples, the behavior of the `rebase-cousins` parameters to the `--rebase-merges` option?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is probably best done by example.

Suppose you have:

```
...--o--*--o--o   <-- main
         \
          \      C--D
           \    /    \
            A--B      G--H   <-- branch
                \    /
                 E--F
```

You want to rebase `branch` onto `main`, with `--rebase-merges`.  The enumeration of `main..branch` lists commits `A` through `H`.  OK, the goal is obvious: Git should copy commits `A-B-(C-D/E-F)` to new commits to make `A'`, `B'`, etc., then run a new `git merge` to make `G'`, and finally copy `H` to make `H'`, all of which come after the tip of main instead of coming after commit `*`.  You end up with:

```
                       C'-D'
                      /    \
                  A'-B'     G'-H'  <-- branch
                 /    \    /
                /      E'-F'
               /
...--o--*--o--o   <-- main
         \
          \      C--D
           \    /    \
            A--B      G--H   [abandoned]
                \    /
                 E--F
```

But suppose you have instead:

```
...--o--*--o---o   <-- main
      \  \
       \  A--B---F--G   <-- branch
        \       /
         C--D--E
```

You run `git checkout branch; git rebase --rebase-merges main`.  The enumeration, `main..branch`, lists commits `A-B-F-G` *and* `C-D-E` too.

Which commits do you want *copied*?  Do you want to keep `C-D-E` as they are, or copy them?  You *do* want to re-perform the merge that produced `F`, merging your new copy `B'` with something, but is that with `E`, or is that with `E'`, the new copy of `E`?

The option allows you to *avoid* copying `C-D-E`, which aren't in the ancestry path from `*` to `H`—`git log --ancestry-path main..branch` will exclude them—or to copy these "cousin" commits anyway.  The default is to exclude them from the copying process, giving:

```
                 A'-B'---------F'-G'  <-- branch
                /             /
...--o--*--o---o   <-- main  /
      \  \                  /
       \  A--B---F--G      /  [abandoned]
        \       /_________/
         C--D--E
```

The `rebase-cousins` option includes them in the copying process, and puts `C'`, the copy of `C`, after `main`, giving:

```
                  C'-D'-E'
                 /       \
                /         \
               / A'-B'-----F'-G'  <-- branch
               |/
...--o--*--o---o   <-- main
      \  \
       \  A--B---F--G   [abandoned]
        \       /
         C--D--E
```

Note that if there are branch names pointing to any of `C`, `D`, or `E`, they won't be moved, regardless of which option you choose.

Comment: Really good explanation. Why do they call those commits "cousins"? To `branch`, C, D, and E are parents (indirect). To `main`, they are cousins (I think) but so are A, B, F, and G right?

Comment: @void.pointer: What do you call the son of your father's (or grandfather's) brother's wife's kid? When we rebase, we—as humans—tend to look at our commits as a linear "children of `*`" relationship, i.e., our main goal is to copy `A-B-F-G` even though `F` is a marriage.  So `A` and `C` are cousins of each other, `B` and `D` are cousins, etc. (Finnish probably has single words for each such relationship :-) )

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I don't think that makes it less confusing. If you think of it in terms of HEAD or other ref, those usually aren't referring to A or B, but in your case it refers to G, which isn't a cousin. Oh well... Thanks for explaining though.

Comment: @void.pointer Let's just say that I don't agree with a lot of Git's terminology too. :-) (This particular one, I find neither good nor terrible.)